# Usage of the word reference

Tags: word-usage, word-request

I would like to use the word reference as follows but I could not find enough example sentences on the Internet.

For example, your company was awarded with a certificate such as ISO9001 and you say

> This certificate is a primary reference to manifest that the standards
>   of hygiene in your company is sufficient to produce foods.

or another example could be

> Certain scores taken on TOEFL exam is primary reference for
>   universities to prove that a student's English skills are sufficient to participate in
>   classes in courses taught in English.

What I mean by "primary reference" is that it is the most trusted or the first asked/wanted or the most well-known document in its field such as ISO certificates for companies or a TOEFL exam result for academic institutions. Is it wrong to say that? What else can I use?

Answer (score 2):

It is not ungrammatical to say *primary reference* but it is a bit clumsy, and in the examples may be the *only* reference. Its typical use is in these examples:

> The primary reference for the XXX widget is the manufacturer's data sheet.
>
> My primary reference when looking for a word is *Roget's Thesaurus*.

I suggest using the word **proof** (which you used as a verb in the second example).
This is given by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/proof) as

> **proof**
>   mass noun
>
> **1** Evidence or argument establishing a fact or the truth of a statement.

So the sentences can be (with other small changes)

> This certificate is **proof** that the standard of hygiene in your company is sufficient to produce foods.
>
> A certain score given for the TOEFL exam is enough **proof** for universities that a student's English skills are sufficient to participate in courses taught in English.